# MongoDB - filter by several array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have documents like this:

```
{
    "_id", "1",
    "myarray": [
        {
           "address": "abc",
           "role": "input",
        }
        {
           "address": "def",
           "role": "output",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id", "2",
    "myarray": [
        {
           "address": "xyz",
           "role": "input",
        }
        {
           "address": "abc",
           "role": "output",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return documents where myarray.address is abc and myarray.role is output, but not the documents where exists myarray.address='abc' and exists myarray.role='output', but the documents where exists element of myarray array:

```
address: "abc",
role: "output"
```

Using the example above, I want only the document with _id=2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to match multiple fields inside an array

```
db.collection.find({ myArray: { $elemMatch: { address: 'abc', role: 'output' }}})
```

Comment: So simple :) My position at MongoDB learning curve seems 1 step from the beginning :)